# Users without the comment privilege unable to edit their own comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, new-users, comment-edits

I've noticed that I can't edit my comments even though they're on my own posts/answers to my questions. I get this:

[image: users w/o post-commenting privilege]

Why must you torture me and waste time with this? It only takes about ten extra seconds to:

- click 'edit'
- <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> the whole comment
- click 'cancel'
- delete the comment
- create a new one and add the edits

This seems like more work on the system than to just allow new users to edit their comments.

Plus, what if there's a typo? What if they added a `:P` at the end and decided it looked stupid?

So what's up with this rule?

Comment: Wait why did this get tagged [tag:bug]? Is it a bug?

Comment: Yes, it's a bug. You should get this message only for auto-generated comments (for example "Possible duplicate of ..." when flagging as duplicate).

Comment: So the question is: Was the comment you tried to change generated by the system?

Comment: The ability for new users to add auto-comments in certain cases is a recent development, so it's not surprising there are a few corner cases where normal comments would be allowed (along with editing) that don't work quite right. Not a super-high-priority bug, but worth eventually fixing.

Comment: @rene The quote "Plus, what if there's a typo? What if they added a :P at the end and decided it looked stupid? (Which it DOES, folks. This isn't Reddit.) What if *gasp* they were wrong about something?" makes it rather obvious that it's not about comments generated by the system.

Comment: The message says that "users *without post commenting privileges*" can't edit, but your suggested workaround is to "create a new one and add the edits". If you don't have post commenting privileges, you can't create a new comment. The message is referring only to auto-generated comments. Auto-generated comments don't have smiley faces in them.

Comment: @CodyGray - you can always comment on your own questions AFAIK.

Comment: Are you saying that you see this message about "auto generated comments" when trying to edit comments that you typed yourself?

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes.

Comment: Why'd you rollback those edits?  They made your question somewhat clearer IMO.

Comment: @NobodyNada Because the title edit was obvious; new users can *only* add comments on their questions. And the content edit was repetitive.

Comment: [Under certain circumstances](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98955/323179), answers can be converted to comments on any question automatically. To make sure people can't edit that comment into spam, they appear to be preventing edits (which explains why it says that). This, however, is a bug, since it should not affect comments on your answers, or your questions (and their answers).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This bug should be fixed, according to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/289146/323179) on a cross-site dupe:

> It wasn't just a wrong message, there was actually a bug that prevented low reputation users from editing their comments, regardless of the edit window time. It is fixed now.